# JSON Schema validate non empty body

Tags: json, schema, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema, serverless

I'm validating an API Gateway request using JSON Schema, I haven't realized it allows empty requests so I want to know if there's a way to validate through the schema that I actually receive something.

This is an example of the schema I have:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"title": "PutPetRequest",
"description": "Accepts a request to create or update a Pet.",
"type": "object",
"required": ["pet"],
"additionalProperties": false,
"properties": {
    "pet": {
        "description": "Pet object type",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "id"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

An empty object `{}` will fail the validation but   (empty, nothing) passes, I've tried `minProperties` and `minItems` but I see the same behavior, is it not possible?

I'm testing with https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Answer (score 1):

JSON Schema validates JSON instances. An empty string is not a valid JSON instance. Therefore, a JSON Schema can't say anything about it. There's nothing there, so there's nothing to validate. Therefore, it's not true or false. JSON does have a `null` value, but   is not the same as `null`.

So, this is not something JSON Schema can express. It appears to be an edge case in AWS API Gateway. I'm not sure if there's a way around it, but there isn't a JSON Schema solution.

Comment: I'm surprised the framework doesn't throw an exception when given a request body of Content-Type: application/json and content = <empty string> -- or simply interpret that as a json 'null', which then *could* be validated with a JSON Schema.

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar scenario, set minLength to 1 which expects atleast 1 character. I know this is not a perfect solution, but this can be used as a work around.

```
scope: {
        title: 'my property',
        description: 'description about my property',
        type: JsonSchemaType.STRING,
        minLength: 1,
      },
```